# Push notifications for a large number of devices

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I am pretty new in the push notifications issue, i want to develop an application
for both android and IOS devices, the application should be able to receive real-time push notifications.

The number of users for this app may reach more than 1,000,000 users, i am searching for a good tool for push-notifications.

The most important thing i am concerned of when sending notifications is low-latency, i want to reach a large number of users **as fast as possible**.

I saw that the service of Google cloud messaging is limited to 1000 users for each request. and any number of users that exceeds this number is sent with batches of 1000, does this effect the speed?

If yes, do you suggest a good push-notifications tool for that purpose?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use 
[OneSignal](http://onesignal.com)

Best and easy to use API of GCM for Android and IOS and much more. This will fulfill all your requirements

Answer (score 1):

We use GCM with our application.

With GCM one notification can send only to 1000 devices (GCM limit). So you must split your array of devices.

For fastest delivery of Notifications: 1. delay_while_idle - set to false 2. time_to_live - set to zero (But you might want to set this higher if their device is offline) 3. Canonical IDs - Make sure Canonical IDs returned by GCM replace the old PushID in database 4. collapse_key - The most important factor - set it to random or TOD to avoid Google to throttle notifications.

I also recommend

[airbop (Android Only)](http://www.airbop.com/)

[Pushy](https://pushy.me/)

Comment: Ok, let's assume i'm using GCM to send a push notification to 50,000
devices.
Does this notification reach the devices in real-time ? 
It is important for me that all users get the message at the same time, and 
that the message arrives in real-time.

Comment: Normally with a TTL set to 0, Google will just push the notification out right away and the devices will receive it within 1-5 seconds. There is no guarantee that all the devices will actually receive it, or that they will get it at the same time. Lots of stuff going on here, You need to have the correct gcm token for the device, the device needs to be online, the device needs a good network connection. you are relying on a 3rd party service with the possibility of a lot of network hops alone the way.