# php speeding up massive gcm push sending

Tags: php, google-cloud-messaging

I have made up a push notification sender in php and I need to speed it up. Currently I have 20 000 subscribers and it takes me about 20 min. to send the same message to all of them and I think it is too long. My sender works as follows:

1) Pick up all subscriber IDs from MySQL DB and put them into array.

2) Foreach all subscriber IDs picked up in step 1 and curl the http request to google server to send a push message - 1 per subscriber ID.

3) Get a response from google server and perform a MySQL query in order to delete a subscriber ID from a DB in case of error - 1 per each subscriber ID.

Currently my script works in a single thread (one foreach loop) and processes subscriber IDs one-by-one. I would like to know if there is a way to make several independent foreach loops in order to process registration IDs in parallel? Or maybe I could make it in several independent PHP processes? Maybe PHP is not the best solution for that and there are some examples of this in other languages? In any case I don`t want to wait for a single foreach loop while it processes all my 20 000 subscribers as it is now. Also I know about bulk sending in 1000 subscriber IDs, but in this case I cannot receive back from google a status of message my message per every subscriber ID. Any ideas would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Well, in GCM it is stated that notification can only send up to 1000 device, so the only thing that you can do is divide the 20,000 subscribers. Here are the [list of things](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) that you must know to make the delivery of notification. For more information, check this related [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325897/push-notifications-for-a-large-number-of-devices).

Comment: Yep, but I have got more likely the PHP problem, rather than GCM one. What I would like to know is how to effectively build up my sender.php architecture in order to make delivery of my push message as fast as possible, taking into consideration that PHP does not have threading as other programming languages do.